# JQuery Mobile Custom Filter - Checkboxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to filter a list of check box items, I want any checked items to be included in the list regardless if they satisfy the search criteria. My idea was to use a custom search and to add a '~' to the front of the data-filtertext attribute of any checked items, then in my search function return true if the '~' is there or if the regular criteria is met. First the code below has huge problems in addition to it not working, note the ! on the test for checked - the status hasn't updated at the point it's being checked, I'd love it if someone could help me make the jquery right. Second, how do I set the data-filtertext properly? Third, thoughts on if any of this is going to work?

```
$('#my_id').find('.ui-btn').on('click', function(){  
         var id = this.htmlFor;  
         var checked = ! $('#' + id).is(':checked');
         if (checked)
         {
           var filter_text = '~' + this.innerHTML;
           this.attributes['data-filtertext'] = filter_text;
         }
         else
         {
           this.attributes['data-filtertext'] = this.innerHTML;
         }     
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to alter the filter text attribute. Instead use the **[filterCallback](http://api.jquerymobile.com/filterable/#option-filterCallback)** event of the filterable widget to see if the item is checked or contains the text.

So given this list:

```
<form>    
    <input data-type="search" id="filterControlgroup-input">
</form>
<div id="myList" data-role="controlgroup" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterControlgroup-input">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2a" id="checkbox-v-2a" data-filtertext="seven">
    <label for="checkbox-v-2a" >One</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2b" id="checkbox-v-2b">
    <label for="checkbox-v-2b">Two</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2c" id="checkbox-v-2c">
    <label for="checkbox-v-2c">Three</label>
</div>
```

Attach the callback event. If the checkbox is checked, return false (don't filter out) otherwise check both the text and data-filtertext to see if the item meets the filter criteria:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
    $("#myList").filterable('option', 'filterCallback', checkedOrMatch);
});

function checkedOrMatch(idx, searchValue) {
    var ret = false;
    var $chkbox = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]')
    var IsChecked = $chkbox.is(':checked');
    if (IsChecked) {
        //always show checked items in list regardless of filter criteria
        ret = false;
    } else if (searchValue && searchValue.length > 0) {
        searchValue = searchValue.toLowerCase();
        var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        var filttext = $chkbox.data("filtertext") || '';
        filttext = filttext.toLowerCase();
        //if neither text nor filtertext contain searchvalue, return true to filter out
        if (text.indexOf(searchValue) < 0 && filttext.indexOf(searchValue) < 0) {
                ret = true; //filter this one out
        }        
    }    
    return ret;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/a249baec/2/)**

Comment: This is awesome.  Is it possible to have dividers inserted in the list that will go hidden if none of the items in that section are visible?

Comment: @user1455270, if you are using autodividers, that happens automatically. See this updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/a249baec/4/

Comment: so it has to be a ul, based on some other examples, i.e. [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/m6zVq/[/link]),  I thought that might be the case.  I need to set the text on the dividers but this is helpful.

Comment: @user1455270, here is an example of changing the autodivider text: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/listview-autodividers-selector/  You can also manually add dividers instead...